# Where to get Sudoku generator in C++?

Tags: sudoku

Here is one - http://ostermiller.org/qqwing/
But sometimes my PHP code (shell_exec('qqwing..')) dies and in syslog I can find segfault errors for qqwing.

So, I'm searching for better generator, but can't find one. Fast and with difficulty levels.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`Sudokuki is a graphical SUDOKU game: Set up a custom sudoku from a magazine or so - Generate a sudoku - Solve a sudoku - Print a sudoku. Translated into: de, en, el, eo, es, fr, ja. Sudokuki is multiplatform GNU/GPL Free Software, in C++`

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudokuki/

If that isn't quite what you want, for some reason, then search further roon SF. I git 292 hits when searching for sudoku

Comment: This is not what I need. No graphical interface. I need command line program.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Did you look through sourceforge?  I got 292 hits when searching for sudoku